# For Loop Replacement: For Loops to Filters

Tags: java, for-loop, filter, stream, file-processing

I'm working on an assignment for a Computer Science III class (Java programming), and in it we have to encode a file based on Huffman coding.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a filename to read from.");
    String filename = in.nextLine();
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    String line, word;
    StringTokenizer token;
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
    while(inputFile.hasNext()){
        line = inputFile.nextLine();
        ArrayList<Character> lineChar = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
            if (line.charAt(i)!=' '){
                lineChar.add(line.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        chars.addAll(lineChar);
    }

    ArrayList<Character> prob = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i=0; i<chars.size(); i++){
        if (!prob.contains(chars.get(i))){
            prob.add(chars.get(i));
        }
    }    
    for (int i=0; i<prob.size(); i++){
        System.out.print("Frequency of " + prob.get(i));
        System.out.println(": " + ((double)Collections.frequency(chars, prob.get(i)))/chars.size());
    }
```

I was working on it in my NetBeans IDE and followed some suggestions. It changed the last two for loops to:

```
    chars.stream().filter((char1) -> (!prob.contains(char1))).forEach((char1) -> {
        prob.add(char1);
    });    

    prob.stream().map((prob1) -> {
        System.out.print("Frequency of " + prob1);
        return prob1;
    }).forEach((prob1) -> {
        System.out.println(": " + ((double) Collections.frequency(chars, prob1)) / chars.size());
    });
```

I am really, really, really intrigued by this, but I find it difficult to trace everything. It obviously operates in the same way as my for loops and after testing I see that it -does- work, but I want to understand why and how. Can anybody give me any insight?

Comment: These are Java 8 streams using lambda expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans did what it could to refactor your code to use java 8 streams, but it can actually be done much better.  For example, it appears that prob is supposed to contain a distinct list of Characters.  In java 8, you can do it like this:

```
List<Character> prob = chars.stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But all you are using prob for is to then calculate how many times each Character appears in chars.  With streams, you can do it without first making a prob list:

```
Map<Character, Long> freq = chars.stream()
   .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            x->x, 
            Collectors.counting()
        )
   );
```

The static methods in Collections class are usually just imported statically, so the above would be written as:

```
Map<Character, Long> freq = chars.stream()
   .collect(groupingBy(x->x, counting());
```

That means, take my stream of chars and make a map.  The key of the map is the char itself (that's what x->x does) and the value of the map is the count of how many times that char occurs in chars.

But that's not all!  The first half of your method goes over the lines of the file and collects the chars.  That can be rewritten with streams as well:

```
Stream<Character> charStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))
        .flatMap(line -> line.chars().mapToObj(i->(char) i));
```

File.lines(..) gives us a stream of lines.  The flatMap part is a bit cryptic, but it unrolls every string into a stream of individual chars and joins the streams so that we have one big stream of chars.

And now we put it all together:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a filename to read from.");
    String filename = in.nextLine();

    Map<Character, Long> freq = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))
            .flatMap(line -> line.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i))
            .collect(groupingBy(x -> x, counting()));

    long total = freq.values().stream().mapToLong(x->x).sum();

    freq.forEach((chr, count) ->
            System.out.format("Frequency of %s: %s%n", chr, ((double) count) / total)
    );

}
```

**Edit:**

To output frequencies in sorted order, do this (using `import static java.util.Comparator.*`):

```
freq.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(comparing(e->e.getValue(), reverseOrder()))
        .forEach(e -> System.out.format("Frequency of %s: %s%n", e.getKey(), (double) e.getValue() / total));
```

We take the map of Character to count, stream its entries, sort them by values in reverse order and print each one out.

Comment: Holy crap that's awesome! How would I sort it in terms of frequency though?

Answer (score 2):

Your IDE replaced some of your code with new Java 8 features - Streams and lambda expressions. You should read about them.

Streams allow you to perform operations on a collection in a pipeline, where only the final (terminal) operation does the actual iteration over the elements (for only as many elements as it requires).

Lambda expressions allow you to write less code when passing anonymous class instances implementing functional interfaces (=interfaces with a single method) to methods.

Here's an attempt to explain what the new code does :

```
chars.stream() // creates a Stream<Character> from your chars List
     .filter((char1) -> (!prob.contains(char1))) // keeps only Characters not contained
                                                 // in prob List
     .forEach((char1) -> {prob.add(char1);}); // iterates over all the elements of
                                              // the Stream (i.e. those that weren't
                                              // filtered out) and adds them to prob   

prob.stream() // creates a Stream<Character> of the prob List
    .map((prob1) -> {
      System.out.print("Frequency of " + prob1);
      return prob1;
     }) // prints "Frequency of " + character for the current Character in the Stream
    .forEach((prob1) -> { // prints the frequency of each character in the Stream
        System.out.println(": " + ((double) Collections.frequency(chars, prob1)) /  chars.size());
     });
```

The `map` operation on the second Stream is a bit strange. Usually map is used to convert a Stream of one type to a Stream of another type. Here it is used to print output and it returns the same Stream. I wouldn't use `map` for that. You can simply move the printing to the `forEach`.

```
prob.stream() // creates a Stream<Character> of the prob List
    .forEach((prob1) -> { // prints the frequency of each character in the Stream
        System.out.print("Frequency of " + prob1);
        System.out.println(": " + ((double) Collections.frequency(chars, prob1)) /  chars.size());
     });
```

Actually, you don't need a Stream for that, since Collections also have a `forEach` method in Java 8 :

```
prob.forEach((prob1) -> { // prints the frequency of each character in the Stream
        System.out.print("Frequency of " + prob1);
        System.out.println(": " + ((double) Collections.frequency(chars, prob1)) /  chars.size());
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

This to me looks like NetBeans refactored your code  to use Java 8's lambda or functional programming operations using the map - reduce from the Stream interface.

For more information on map() / reduce()/ stream interface refer [to this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

Please read the suggestions that the IDE provides before you apply them :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should read about the [java.util.Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) package, to get a first impression of how the API is designed and for what purpoeses.

Here is what your first loop does, in word form:

- Iterate over the values from 0 to chars.size()-1 and add the corresponding element from `chars` to `prob`, but only if it's not already there.

With the Stream API added to Java with **Java 8** such tasks can be written in a functional programming style which focuses on the *"how is it done"* not on the *"with what is ist done"*.

```
chars.stream()
    .filter(char1 -> !prob.contains(char1))
    .forEach(char1 -> {
        prob.add(char1);
    });
```

- `ArrayList` implements `Collection<T>` and therefore the method [stream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--).
- This stream (all elements from the Collection in a pipeline) is being filtered (by your former if-statement)
- On the stream of the remaining elements, execute the final operation `prop.add`

This might be a bit too much for now, but you can change the last operation (.forEach) to be even clearer:

```
//...
.forEach(prop::add);
```

For better insight or debuggin purposes you might find [Stream#peek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) interesting which let.